# Eight edits rejected with an invalid and unsubstantiated claim

Tags: support, bug, tag-wiki

**Devs:** Please see GAThrawn's answer for the "bug".  If possible, please reverse the edit rejections.  --Matthew Read

## Summary

Following up as to why did I have so many rejected edits I've started to analyze all suggestions that I've made to find the ones rejected and try to learn from the mistake committed.

What brought me here is the fact that I've committed no mistakes whatsoever. The reason behind the rejection of my edit suggestions was invalid and unsubstantiated.

Eight edits have been rejected with the following claim:

> There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist

But after analyzing each one of them and performed a search for questions with those tags, feels like I've paid the price for someone else's "mistake", after all, questions exist for each one of the tags edited:

- Got prevented from editing during 7 days.
- My record for future edits shows poor editing skills.
- I've wasted a Sunday afternoon instead of invested it to the community.

### I'm asking what can be done to set the records strait on this one?

---

## List of Reject Edits

1. [Jul 15 suggested edit on motorola-blur tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1567):

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answer that uses this tag: [Why is there a blank white space under some Apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24189/16265)
2. [Jul 15 suggested edit on motorola-blur tag wiki excerpt](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1568):

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answer that uses this tag: [Why is there a blank white space under some Apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24189/16265)
3. [Jul 15 suggested edit on huawei-ascend-ii tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1563)

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answer that uses this tag: [Change “me” picture](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22886/16265)
4. [Jul 15 suggested edit on huawei-ascend-ii tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1564)

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answer that uses this tag: [Change “me” picture](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22886/16265)
5. [Jul 15 suggested edit on huawei-u8160 tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1561)

   Justification:** `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answers that uses this tag:

   - [all unity 3d games force close](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25927/16265)
   - [does Cyanogenmod 7.2 Madteam release 16/6 on Vodafone 858 support USB host?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24811/16265)
6. [Jul 15 suggested edit on huawei-u8160 tag wiki excerpt](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1562)

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answers that uses this tag:

   - [all unity 3d games force close](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25927/16265)
   - [does Cyanogenmod 7.2 Madteam release 16/6 on Vodafone 858 support USB host?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24811/16265)
7. [Jul 15 suggested edit on huawei-u8500 tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1557)

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answers that uses this tag:

   - [Huawei U8500 Wifi Problem: Unable to start WLAN](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25092/16265)
   - [Wifi shows error on Huawei U8500](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24572/16265)
8. [Jul 15 suggested edit on huawei-u8500 tag wiki excerpt](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1558)

   Justification: `There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist`
   Answers that uses this tag:

   - [Huawei U8500 Wifi Problem: Unable to start WLAN](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25092/16265)
   - [Wifi shows error on Huawei U8500](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24572/16265)

Comment: (Not really directed at Zuul, but everyone looking for a way to help improve the site.) For future reference, it would probably be more helpful to all if tag wikis were created for popular tags that don't have them. If you pull up the tag list and [sort by popularity](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) you should quickly see which tags lack descriptions and _really_ need them.

Comment: Maybe a system mod can re-accept the edits?

Comment: Given GAThrawn's post I'm going to throw on the bug tag here.  I can't do anything but maybe a dev can.  I'm on my phone and can't edit properly so please feel free to revise the post if you want instead of having my notice there.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thank you for the intervention! *(hail the dev)* :)

Comment: @AlEverett Usually I check on tag wikis that are present on questions that I'm looking at, either for a simple reading or to provide an answer. But I'll keep that in mind. *(if ain't very popular, don't bother!)*

Comment: @Zuul: Very unpopular tags will be auto-deleted by the system, too, whether or not there is a tag wiki associated with them.

Comment: @AlEverett I was under the belief that only unused tags were subject to automatic deletion..

Comment: @Zuul: Nope. I'll go search for the post, but I believe if a tag has 1 (or fewer) questions with 1 (or fewer) net votes, it will be deleted after 90 days. That's the source for almost all of the [tag:untagged] questions I find every once in a while.

Comment: Found it: [Monthly routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/21960)

Comment: @AlEverett I see, tags older than 6 months get deleted if used only once! This routine check is runs on a monthly basis. Tks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I was the person who rejected those, though from memory you had a queue of about 20 suggested edits on that morning and I'm pretty sure I approved at least half of them. It stuck in my mind because that was an awful lot of edit suggestions from one person, and some of them were very long.

I'm sorry if I caused any offence by this, one reason I didn't pick any of the default rejection reasons but instead wrote out a custom one explaining why I'd rejected them was so that you could see why I'd done it.

> There's no questions tagged with this, it has no reason to exist

That was my comment as I rejected those edits.

From memory all of your edits were creating new Tag Wiki's and Tag Wiki Excerpts. The very first thing I do when I see a tag wiki edit of any kind in the queue is click the tag, read through the questions currently tagged with that tag, and then come back and see if the wiki edit suggestion seems to match the intent of the questions.

When I clicked through the tags you've highlighted above I honestly couldn't see any questions tagged with them. In a couple of cases, because it did look odd to be submitting so many tag wiki's for non-existent tags, as well as clicking through to the tag and going through the tabs (newest, faq, votes, active, unanswered) I also ran searches for the [tag name] on the site, and still couldn't see any questions tagged with those tags.

Looking now, there definitely are questions tagged with the tags you point out, and if you re-submitted your edits, I wouldn't reject them again. As to what happened on the day, I genuinely couldn't find any questions using those tags, which means that anything in them will be automatically deleted by the StackExchange engine. However when I look at the edit dates on those questions, a lot of them had the tag in question added before I serached for it, which is odd, and I can't explain what's happened there.

I don't know what happened there, and I'm sorry if I caused you any offence, but as far as I could see at the time what I said was true when I looked, and I can't explain why what I was seeing was different from what you saw.

Comment: Tks for the reply. On July 15, I've suggested 12 edits, you've approved [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1565), [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1566), [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1559) and [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1560). (one-third got approved) :)

Comment: To be clear, no offence was taken, I've just "complained" due to the -x on my profile. When I'm performing any type of action on any SE site, I try to be as productive as possible, and accept being "punished" when I'm not on the top of my game. This was not the case, hence the reason for my question here.

Comment: I do price the person whose integrity cannot be questioned, and your answer proves this much! +1 :)